# Make text to break under own

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is make `a` tag text to start new line under it own text not under numbers

```css
ul.myul {
  counter-reset: li;
}

ul.myul li {
  counter-increment: li;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.myul li a::before {
  content: "0" counter(li);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'poppinsbold';
  color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <ul class="myul">
    <li><a>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a>lorem ipsum lorem</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I want actually, it should goes to new line after red line, not behind the redline:

```css
ul.myul {
  counter-reset: li;
}

ul.myul li {
  counter-increment: li;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.myul li a::before {
  content: "0" counter(li);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'poppinsbold';
  color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.myul::after {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 78px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <ul class="myul">
    <li><a>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a>lorem ipsum lorem</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The dupe actually does not answer this specific question.

Comment: I assume you want the second line starting with ipsum to be under the lorem of the first line, right?

Answer (score 1):

@CBroe had already mentioned it correctly in the comment. The ul CSS property list-style-position: outside; is the right way to go here.

```css
ul.myul {
  counter-reset: li;  
  
}

ul.myul li {    
  counter-increment: li;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  position: relative;
}
ul.myul li::before {
  content: "0" counter(li) ".";
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'poppinsbold';
  color: red;  
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;    
}

.myul::after {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 86px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px">
  <ul class="myul">
    <li>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</li>    
    <li><a>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a>lorem ipsum lorem</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Inside or outside? You say outside but use inside.... And it seems to be the padding-left that does the heavy lifting